# Rails 3 fragment caching not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

Trying to get fragment caching to work in Rails 3.0.9.

I have set this in development.rb:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

And restarted the server (webrick). Then set this in my view:

```
<% cache("tags_json") do %>
    [Content to be cached]
<% end %>
```

And when I reload the page, I don't see anything in the log about caching. Reload the page again, same results, no cache has been written or read. There is also no cache files created anywhere in the file tree as far as I can tell.

I am new to caching so I am sure that I've just forgotten to set something up. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are there files in your tmp/cache directory?

Comment: No. Sorry for taking so long to respond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside configuring ActionController's cache performing, you also need to set cache store in general config.
Put

> **config.cache_store = xyz,abc**

cache_store configures which cache store to use for Rails caching. Options include one of the symbols 
**:memory_store, :file_store, :mem_cache_store, or an object that implements the cache API**.

It defaults to :file_store if the directory tmp/cache exists, and to :memory_store otherwise.
I'll recommend to use [dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) store in-conjunction with memcached client.